# sp- How to get the rigth value for Create / Update List

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a problem that I can't get the right value in the listItemInfo.
I tried following to see the output of the code.

```js
alert(listItemInfo.toString());
```

The first alert is exactly 12 but the second is 1213.
I need to check if it is 12 or 13, etc. What is wrong in the script?
Here it is.
Code:

```js
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
     var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListA');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml( '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
            );
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync( 
       Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
       Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += oListItem.get_item('ID');
                    //'\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
                  
        for (var i = 0; i < listItemInfo.length; i++){
            if (listItemInfo.split() == 12) {
                var siteUrl = 'https://........'
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl); 
                var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListA');
                var oListItem = oList.getItemById(12);
                this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(12);
                alert("ist gleich 12");
                oListItem.set_item('Location', 'blub');
                oListItem.update(); 
                  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceess, onQueryFailed);               
            }
              
        }
        alert(listItemInfo.toString());} 
        
}
function onQuerySucceess() {
   alert('Item updated!');
}
 
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Aren't you concatenating the item Ids yourself, producing 1213?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Nikolay i have a list with field Name Usersemail and Location. I have a sharepoint site in which the user can select an location. I read the useremail from current user and i can save the useremail and location in my list. For the first time it is ok. If the user select again another location then i have 2 entries in my list for the same user but i need only 1 entire for 1 user.

Comment: I can work with the list setting unique value for the usersemail field. But in this case i have evry time the first location form the user and not the aktually selected. so i need to identifiy if the usersemails exist in the list i need only an update for the field location. If not i need a new entrie

Comment: so i try a way to identify the row i the first step with the ID, so i can understand , bascuase i very new in JS. so i dont need to idetify only the ID=12 . I need to check in the loop all entries in the list so i can identify if the user exist or not. I need that the alert turn me 12 , then 13, then 14 and so on. If tahts work i will change the script to check with email adress.

Answer (score 0):

To help you better, can you describe the problem in detail? What function need to be achieved?

In your code, the value of `listItemInfo` is a concatenation of all itemIDs. Since `alert(listItemInfo.toString());` is placed in the while loop, it will alert itemID values in turn, such as 12, 1213...

By the way, are you trying to change the value of the Item which itemID is 12?

I tried to modify your code for testing and it worked, you can refer to it.

My Test result:

```
function retrieveListItems() {
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
     var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListTest');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml( '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
            );
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync( 
       Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
       Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += oListItem.get_item('ID');
                    //'\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
            if (listItemInfo == 12) {
                var siteUrl = 'https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx'
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl); 
                var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListTest');
                var oListItem = oList.getItemById(12);
                this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(12);
                alert("ist gleich 12");
                oListItem.set_item("Title", "New Title3");
                oListItem.update(); 
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceess, onQueryFailed);               
            }      
    }     
}
function onQuerySucceess() {
   alert('Item updated!');
}
 
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

[image]

------------------------------------update------------------------------------

Please try to put  `var listItemInfo = '';`  into the while loop.then it will alert turn 12 , then 13, then 14 and so on.

Full code:

```
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
     var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test2');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml( '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
            );
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync( 
       Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
       Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += oListItem.get_item('ID');
                    //'\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
                  
        for (var i = 0; i < listItemInfo.length; i++){
            if (listItemInfo.split() == 12) {
                var siteUrl = 'https://........'
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl); 
                var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListA');
                var oListItem = oList.getItemById(12);
                this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(12);
                alert("ist gleich 12");
                oListItem.set_item('Location', 'blub');
                oListItem.update(); 
                  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceess, onQueryFailed);               
            }
              
        }
        alert(listItemInfo.toString());} 
        
}
function onQuerySucceess() {
   alert('Item updated!');
}
 
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Hello Zella i have a list with field Name Usersemail and Location. I have a sharepoint site i which the user can select an location. I read the useremail from current user and i can save the useremail and location in my list. For the first time it is ok. If the user select again another location then i have 2 entries in my list for the same user but i need only 1 entire for 1 user.

Comment: I can work with the list setting unique value for the usersemail field. But in this case i have evry time the first location form the user and not the aktually selected. so i need to identifiy if the usersemails exist in the list i need only an update for the field location. If not i need a new entrie.

Comment: so i try a way to identify the row i the first step with the ID, so i can understand , bascuase i very new in JS. so i dont need to idetify only the ID=12 . I need to check in the loop all entries in the list so i can identify if the user exist or not. I need that the alert turn me 12 , then 13, then 14 and so on. If tahts work i will change the script to check with email adress. Thank you very much for you help and sorry if my englisch is a little bit wrong

Comment: Hi @user18398418 ,please try to put  < var listItemInfo = ''; >  into the while loop, then it will alert turn 12 , then 13, then 14 and so on.  I have modified the answer above, you can refer to it.